# How to fillna by groups?

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
id day name
1  10  kate
1  11  paul
1  12  paul 
2  1   Nan
2  2   leonardo
2  3   Nan
3  1   Nan
```

How can I rewrite this function  `df['name'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)`, so that I get this result?

```
id day name
1  10  kate
1  11  paul
1  12  paul 
2  1   Nan
2  2   leonardo
2  3   leonardo
3  1   Nan
```

Comment: df['name'].groupby(id).fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
id,day,name
1,10,kate
1,11,paul
1,12,paul 
2,1,
2,2,leonardo
2,3,
3,1,"""), sep=',')
>>> df
    id  day name
0   1   10  kate
1   1   11  paul
2   1   12  paul
3   2   1   NaN
4   2   2   leonardo
5   2   3   NaN
6   3   1   NaN
```

We can use a `groupby` and the `ffill()` method to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df['name'] = df.groupby(['id'])['name'].ffill()
>>> df
    id  day name
0   1   10  kate
1   1   11  paul
2   1   12  paul
3   2   1   NaN
4   2   2   leonardo
5   2   3   leonardo
6   3   1   NaN
```

Comment: But this will return only one row, won't it?

Comment: The answer has been updated to replace the `name` column in the `DataFrame` instead of returning just a column :)

Answer (score 0):

You can forward fill with a groupby like this:

```
df = df.groupby(['id'], as_index=False).apply(lambda group: group.ffill())
```

This will also fill other na columns if you have them. You can just use name column if you wanted to